Mapbox/Maplibre raycast with only a projection matrix and georeferenced objects
I guess this could be considered a continuation of this question so please check it out for context about his one, especially the JSFiddle reported in said question.
I'm basically trying to achieve the same, however I'm trying to plot georeferenced lines (builing them from points), but I still need to be able to make the raycaster functional.
My main issue was that if I plotted them without "moving" them closer to the center of the THREE.js world (by using what provided in the snippet below), otherwise the rendering was utterly imprecise (those lines need a precision of more or less 1/10 of meter to look decent and due to gpu tansforms their coordinates were being mangled).
...
this.center = MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(map.getCenter(), 0);
...
// lines is an array of lines, and each line is an array of georeferenced 3d points
lines.forEach((points) => { 
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points.map(({lng, lat, elev}) => {
    const { x, y, z } = MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat([lng, lat], elev);
    return new THREE.Vector3(x1 - center.x, y - center.y, z - center.z);
  }));
  const line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
  this.scene.add(line);
});

So, their visualization works correctly this way, but only if I don't consider scaling and rotating in the camera transforms (so by setting this.cameraTransform = new THREE.Matrix4().setPosition(x, y, z); in the fiddle mentioned above).
Clearly, by using this approach, the transformation about scale and rotation, that I supposed are indeed needed to make the raycaster work, aren't working anymore.
Whatever solution found online about positioning 3d objects with their lng/lat coordinates is quite superficial and lacks proper documentation, so I couldn't really figure out how to make this...
Any idea?
    class GraphsLayer {
      type = 'custom';
      renderingMode = '3d';
      constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
      }
      async onAdd (map, gl) {
        this.map = map;
        const { width, height } = map.transform;
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(28, width / height, 0.1, 1e6);
        const centerLngLat = map.getCenter();
        this.center = MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(centerLngLat, 0);
        const { x, y, z } = this.center;
        const s = this.center.meterInMercatorCoordinateUnits();
        const scale = new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(s, s, -s);
        const rotation = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(
          new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(-0.5 * Math.PI),
          new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.PI),
        );
        this.cameraTransform = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(scale, rotation).setPosition(x, y, z); // displaying of segments don't work with this
        this.cameraTransform = new THREE.Matrix4().setPosition(x, y, z); // this instead works for displaying but not for the raycaster
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, linewidth: 3 });

        const segments = await (await fetch('lines.json')).json();

        segments.forEach((s) => {
          const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(s.coos.map(p => {
            const { x: x1, y: y1, z: z1 } = MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat([p[0], p[1]], p[2]);
            return new THREE.Vector3(x1 - x, y1 - y, z1 - z);
          }));
          const line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
          this.scene.add(line);
        });

        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
          canvas: map.getCanvas(),
          context: gl,
          antialias: true,
        });
        this.renderer.autoClear = false;
        this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
      }

      render (gl, matrix) {
        this.camera.projectionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4()
          .fromArray(matrix)
          .multiply(this.cameraTransform);
        this.renderer.resetState();
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
      }

      raycast ({ x, y }) {
        const { width, height } = this.map.transform;
        const camInverseProjection = this.camera.projectionMatrix.clone().invert();
        const cameraPosition = new THREE.Vector3().applyMatrix4(camInverseProjection);
        const mousePosition = new THREE.Vector3(
          (x / width) * 2 - 1, 1 - (y / height) * 2, 1,
        ).applyMatrix4(camInverseProjection);
        const viewDirection = mousePosition.sub(cameraPosition).normalize();

        this.raycaster.set(cameraPosition, viewDirection);

        // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
        var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children, true);
        console.log(intersects)
      }
    }

This works for displaying, but the raycaster isn't working.
UPDATE:
I put everything I got on here.

Hi there! Could you please create a fiddle with what you have? Just take my original and adapt it with your code. Most important of all, please add some data, e.g. at least one line from lines.json as a constant array declared as part of the fiddle :)

Hi @Isolin, thanks for your reply! Appended a jsfiddle on the question, with some data as requested.

Thank you, I hope I will find time to look on it in the following days.

You are using a Maplibre-gl, a different library than the referenced question. Their APIs are not compatible, that explains the issues you have experienced. Both of then are well visible using some simple debugging. If you console.log some variables in the raycast method, you will see that they are wrong: undefined and NaN.
Mouse move event
Deconstruction of the mousemove event fails, because you need to pass the point property. At least this is how it works on FF, I did not check any other browsers.
map.on('mousemove', (e) => graphsLayer.raycast(e.point)) // < add .point here

Canvas size
The API you are using is different to Mapbox. There are no width and height properties in the Map object. You need to get the canvas and extract them out from there.
const {
    clientWidth,
    clientHeight
} = this.map.getCanvas();

Of course you later use the new variable names.
const mousePosition = new THREE.Vector3(
    (x / clientWidth) * 2 - 1, 1 - (y / clientHeight) * 2, 1,
).applyMatrix4(camInverseProjection);

Scaling and rotation
In my answer to the original question I stressed out that MapBox was (perhaps still is) using a different coordinate system than OpenGL/WebGL/Three.js. So the scaling and rotation were needed to compensate for that. Maplibre-gl, as its name suggests, is oriented on OpenGL, thus there is no more conversion necessary. That is also why you correctly discovered,
that omitting the rotation and scaling yields correct display.
// No need for this
// const s = this.center.meterInMercatorCoordinateUnits();
// const scale = new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(s, s, -s);
// const rotation = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(
//     new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(-0.5 * Math.PI),
//     new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.PI),
// );
// this.cameraTransform = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(scale, rotation).setPosition(x, y, z);

// Just keep this
this.cameraTransform = new THREE.Matrix4().setPosition(x, y, z); 

Picking threshold
Since lines have no real surface, exact intersection of the view ray with a line is rarely to find. Instead, three.js computes the minimal distance of the ray to each line and consider it an intersection if below a given threshold. The params property sets the threshold, by default to 1 world unit.
If you look at your scene scale and distances returned by the raycaster, they are somewhere around 2e-6 even if the mouse is far away. Your would space is microscopic. So in order to get just the very few lines in the closest neighborhood of the mouse pointer you need to adjust the threshold to something like.
//add this after this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
this.raycaster.params.Line.threshold = 1e-8;

But do not forget, that you may still get more than a single result, e.g. close to junctions where several lines meet.

Thanks @isolin, sorry for wasting time this way. Actually I already got to a similar situation with my tests too, however there's an issue that keeps up and made me wonder if the problem was still scaling/rotation. Basically the intersects list I get this way is always the full list of lines. I corrected the script with the changes you kindly provided me with, here, but as you can see the raycaster is basically intercepting everything, all the times...

Sure, that is the intended behavior. Please read the docs https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObjects and you will find that the results of intersectObjects are sorted by distance. In order to see the closest result, just console.log(intersects[0]). Feel free to decide what kind of picking you want for your app. You may for example 1) pick all within a distance, or 2) pick the closest within a distance or 3) pick the closest independent of the distance.

I'm sorry but I cannot understand. The documentation states it receives an array of objects and checks for intersection with them all, returning intersection, that to me is, all the object that intercept the ray casted by the pointer, not all the objects in the scene. In my case it's like the pointer is casting a ray as "wide" as the whole scene, so it looks like all the objects in the scene always intersect the ray all the times, independently from where the pointer is. Other examples in the docs instead seem to work accordingly, returning only the object(s) that are below the cursor...

I updated the answer accordingly. See the last paragraph.
